# C/C++ cross platform Timer As csharp System.Threading.Timer no boost or other

Tags: c++, timer, cross-platform

looking for c/c++ equivalent to c# csharp System.Threading.Timer
that can take function call back and run on different thread
please no boost or other fat library

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `std::thread` and [`std::jthread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread/jthread)

Something like this

```
std::jthread timer([capture](int param){ 
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  DoIt(capture, param); 
}, 3);
```

std::this_thread::sleep_* can be added to the

Comment: i dont see jthread accepting interval parameter

Comment: @user63898 you can try for something like this.